# How to add onclick="return func()" by addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I have a link: `<a href="/somelink" id="link_test" onclick="return func(event);">Link</a>`.

I want to remove this `onclick` attribute and add a `click` event listener by `addEventListener`.

I tried:

```
ge("link_test").addEventListener('click',function(){
  return func(window.event);
},false);
```

also:

```
ge("link_test").addEventListener('click',"return func(window.event);",false);
```

No result. Is it possible to do it by `addEventListener` (and how)?

PS: actually I have a cross-browser variant of `addEventListener` func, but not important in this case.

Comment: Your first try should work, but what do you mean by no result? Is the func() that is not run or is it the link not going to where it should (as it should if the value returned from fn is not truthy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var anch = document.getElementById("link_test");
anch.addEventListener ("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    func(event) 
}, false);
```

Do you mean something like this